create columns based on date values for pivot table in my sql
I have a table with sample data as:
MEDNAME      QUANTITY   SALES_DATE
XEPRAMYCIN      4       2024-10-27
FEVITAMOL       2       2024-10-27
XEPRAMYCIN      1       2024-10-26
FEVITAMOL       1       2024-10-26
XEPRAMYCIN      3       2024-10-25
FEVITAMOL       3       2024-10-25

I need to create a pivot table making SALES_DATE value as column name. I've the static query for it but I need to make a dynamic query for SALES_DATE values.
SELECT
  `MEDNAME`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `SALES_DATE` = '2024-10-27' THEN `QUANTITY` ELSE 0 END) AS `2024-10-27`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `SALES_DATE` = '2024-10-26' THEN `QUANTITY` ELSE 0 END) AS `2024-10-26`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `SALES_DATE` = '2024-10-25' THEN `QUANTITY` ELSE 0 END) AS `2024-10-25`
FROM
  `MED_TBL`
GROUP BY
  `MEDNAME`;

How to generate dynamic query for this?
I have tried but I do not have idea how to write such query.
START TRANSACTION;
 SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    `SALES_DATE`
  ) INTO @sql
  FROM `MED_TBL`;
  
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `MEDNAME` , ',  @sql, ' FROM `MED_TBL` GROUP BY `MEDNAME`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP?

Removed php tag, since there is no mention of PHP in the question.

A canned stored procedure:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Use,
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
       CONCAT(
           "SUM(CASE WHEN SALES_DATE = '", SALES_DATE, 
           "' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) AS `", 
           SALES_DATE, "`"
       )
   ) INTO @columns
FROM MED_TBL;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT MEDNAME, ', 
    @columns, 
    ' FROM MED_TBL GROUP BY MEDNAME'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

See example
Note GROUP_CONCAT has a limit of 1024 characters, adjust accordingly.
Reference
